# How to add new custom page in Timber Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, timber, custom-pages

Wordpress version: 6.4.3
"timber/timber": "2.x-dev"
Starter theme: upstatement/timber-starter-theme

I understand you require composer to install timber, no longer require plugin
but how to new custom page in timber wordpress?

in page attributes, i cannot see the tempalete dropdown to select the template
[image: Page attributes]

Did i miss out something?

I did create contact.php

```
<?php
/**
 * The main template file
 * This is the most generic template file in a WordPress theme
 * and one of the two required files for a theme (the other being style.css).
 * It is used to display a page when nothing more specific matches a query.
 * E.g., it puts together the home page when no home.php file exists
 *
 * Methods for TimberHelper can be found in the /lib sub-directory
 *
 * @package  WordPress
 * @subpackage  Timber
 * @since   Timber 0.1
 */

$context          = Timber::context();
$context['posts'] = Timber::get_posts();
$context['foo']   = 'bar';
$templates        = array( 'contact.twig' );
Timber::render( $templates, $context );
```

also the contact.twig

```
{% extends "base.twig" %}

{% block content %}
    {% include "partial/altHero.twig" %}

    <h1>Contact</h1>

{% endblock %}
```

I am not sure, what else do i missout?
and i cannot install the timber plugin as well,
error msg when i try to insstall timber plugin
**Plugin could not be activated because it triggered a fatal error.
**

Your help is most appreciated
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hUYd.png)

ok, finally solved it

you need add comment in your custom php page
template name and description

without it, it will not display

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: My Custom Page<<<<
 * Description: A Page Template with a darker design.<<<<
 * The main template file
 * This is the most generic template file in a WordPress theme
 * and one of the two required files for a theme (the other being style.css).
 * It is used to display a page when nothing more specific matches a query.
 * E.g., it puts together the home page when no home.php file exists
 *
 * Methods for TimberHelper can be found in the /lib sub-directory
 *
 * @package  WordPress
 * @subpackage  Timber
 * @since   Timber 0.1
 */

$context          = Timber::context();
$context['posts'] = Timber::get_posts();
$context['foo']   = 'bar';
$templates        = array( 'contact.twig' );
Timber::render( $templates, $context );
```